# If statement: how to code "if" so that it works when there are hits

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

Does someone know how to do an `if` statement when I want to specify that I want the code happen only if there are results for the search?

For example when user searches for a pie recipe and there are results then the `if` should be evoked. But when user searches something that doesn't get any results then `else` should be done.

```
var searchword = $('#search').val(); //search is id for the input field

if (searchword ...? ) {
 // there's a hit for the search and code continues
 }

else {
// there aren't any hits so this code continues
}
```

I first tried to use `if (searchword > 0) { }`  but that's not really doing what I want it to do. So the user should be able to write on the input field but if there are search results then the `if` should be done and if not then the `else`.

Here's the hole part of the code if it helps to understand:

```
function () {
        var searchword = $('#search').val();

        if ( // statement here ) {

          $.ajax({
            url: "https://webservice.informatik.umu.se/webservice_livsmedel/getlivsmedel.php",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            jsonp: "getLivsMedel",
            data: {
              callback: 'getLivsMedel',
              namn: searchword
            }
          });

        } else {
          $("tbody").empty();
        }   
}

function getLivsMedel(response) {

    var livsmedel = response.livsmedel;

    livsmedel.forEach(function (produkt) {
        $('#tabell > tbody').append('<tr>' + '<td>' + produkt.namn + '</td>' + '<td>' + produkt.energi + '</td>' + '<td>' + produkt.kolhydrater + '</td>'
+ '<td>' + produkt.protein + '</td>' + '<td>' + produkt.fett + '</td>' + '</tr>');
    });

}
```

Comment: Is that ajax call the thing doing the search? If so, it should not be in an `if` statement, it should be run first and then its callback (which you don't show) should have an `if` to do do something depending on whether there were results.

Comment: Yes it's ajax. Are you sure? I added the callback function to the question.
`

Comment: just to clarify, what do you want to test in the if statement? The length of the search string or the amount of results?

Comment: I want to test if there are any results

Comment: It's not possible to test if there are any results before you make the ajax call (because the ajax call is what will tell you whether there are any results!)  You have to put the `if` statement in the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated as per comments**

```
   function () {
                var searchword = $('#search').val();      

                  $.ajax({
                    url: "https://webservice.informatik.umu.se/webservice_livsmedel/getlivsmedel.php",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    jsonp: "getLivsMedel",
                    data: {
                      callback: 'getLivsMedel',
                      namn: searchword
                    }
                  });
                }



function getLivsMedel(response) {
    if(!$.isEmptyObject(response)){
        var livsmedel = response.livsmedel;

        livsmedel.forEach(function (produkt) {
            $('#tabell > tbody').append('<tr>' + '<td>' + produkt.namn + '</td>' + '<td>' + produkt.energi + '</td>' + '<td>' + produkt.kolhydrater + '</td>'
    + '<td>' + produkt.protein + '</td>' + '<td>' + produkt.fett + '</td>' + '</tr>');
        });
    }   
   else {
          $("tbody").empty();
        } 
    }
```

Comment: That's not what I was going for. I was trying to make it possible that user writes a search and if there are results for it, then the `if` were executed. And if there are no results, then `else`. So this way `lenght > 0` user wouldn't get `else` in case there are no results. Only in case user didn't write anything..

Comment: Thanks for the edited version. But it's still not working properly. The `else` part is not being executed. I tried even `else { alert("hello"); }` and  it didn't work. And neither `$("tbody").empty();`.

Comment: Are you getting a response every time?try some keyword which has no results

Comment: what are you getting in response when you have no search results can u post it here?

Comment: I'm not getting anything. Even the console doesn't show any errors. When I click the button only empty table is shown.

Comment: alert your response and try by replacing condition with `if(response.length > 0)` here in my snippet

Comment: I tried but it didn't alert anything. And didn't show any errors/warnings on console

Comment: livsmedel.count gives what value?have you checked?

Comment: It says undefined

Answer (score 0):

See if this is what you're looking for.

```js
$('#sok-button').click(function() {
  var searchQuery = $('#livsmedelsSokOrd').val();

  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://webservice.informatik.umu.se/webservice_livsmedel/getlivsmedel.php',
    data: {
      namn: searchQuery
    },
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data) {
      $('#tabell > tbody').html('');
      getLivsMedel(data);
    },
    error: function(req, status, err) {
      console.log('something went wrong');
    }
  });

});


function getLivsMedel(response) {

  var livsmedel = response.livsmedel;

  if (livsmedel.length > 0) {
    livsmedel.forEach(function(produkt) {

      $('#tabell > tbody').append('<tr>' + '<td>' + produkt.namn + '</td>' + '<td>' + produkt.energi + '</td>' + '<td>' + produkt.kolhydrater + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + produkt.protein + '</td>' + '<td>' + produkt.fett + '</td>' + '</tr>');

    });
  } else {
    $('#tabell > tbody').html('None');
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="" id="livsmedelsSokOrd" value="" />
<button id="sok-button">
Search
</button>

<span id="tabell">

</span>

<table id="tabell">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Namn</th>
      <th>Energi</th>
      <th>kolhydrater</th>
      <th>Protein</th>
      <th>Fett</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>

</table>
```